# Apache Shiro combined with LDAP

Tags: security, ldap

I integrated Apache Shiro with a dummy user and it works just fine! But this framework has no tutorials online?! It's very hard to get into it as a beginner.

Can somebody help me integrating a ldap integration. I have only found information that it is not that difficult :-/

I started with configuring the realm:

```
   [main]
    myRealm = org.apache.shiro.realm.ldap.AbstractLdapRealm
```

But what to do next? How to configure it?

Thank's for any help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The AbstractLdapRealm is abstract - you can't instantiate it directly or declare it as your realm.  You will have to subclass this one and implement the necessary abstract methods.

You won't need to do this upon the next Shiro release - there is currently an issue open (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SHIRO-127) to have a concrete implementation that can be used out of the box so 95% of end-users won't have to subclass the AbstractLdapRealm.

Comment: Just an update - the latest Shiro 1.1 distribution includes a new JndiLdapRealm: http://shiro.apache.org/static/current/apidocs/org/apache/shiro/realm/ldap/JndiLdapRealm.html

The JavaDoc shows how to define it in an INI config.

Answer (score 4):

This could be of little help. Check for the whole tutorial it covers simple and LDAP authentication.
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-apacheshiro/

Comment: Thank you I already managed to do that. And in fact your link helped a lot. If somebody needs help with connecting shiro to some ldap put a comment here and link your question, I will help you guys

Answer (score 3):

Here is working example.

active.ini

```
ldapRealm = org.apache.shiro.realm.activedirectory.ActiveDirectoryRealm
ldapRealm.url = ldap://ldapserver:389
```

Code:

```
Factory<SecurityManager> ldapFactory = new IniSecurityManagerFactory("classpath:active.ini");
SecurityManager sManager = ldapFactory.getInstance();
SecurityUtils.setSecurityManager(sManager);

Subject currentUser = SecurityUtils.getSubject();

        if (!currentUser.isAuthenticated()) {
            UsernamePasswordToken token = new UsernamePasswordToken("user", "password");
            try {
                currentUser.login(token);
            } catch (UnknownAccountException ex) {
                logger.info("Unknown user");
            } catch (IncorrectCredentialsException ex) {
                logger.info("Incorrect credentials");
            } catch (LockedAccountException ex) {
                logger.info("Account is Locked");
            } catch (AuthenticationException ex) {
                logger.info("Authentication Exception");
            }
        }

        logger.info("User [" + currentUser.getPrincipal() +"] logged succesfully");
        currentUser.logout();
```

Comment: Those classes seem to be dropped with 1.2.2. Is there a code example with the current Shiro classes?

Comment: @user1069528 Seems they are still present in Shiro Core 1.2.3. Did you download the right jar from the project website?

Answer (score 0):

if using Spring as the core framework, you can also use the application context XML to define the realms as:

```
    <bean id="ldapRealm" class="org.apache.shiro.realm.activedirectory.ActiveDirectoryRealm">
            <property name="url" value="ldap:/ldapserver:389" />
    </bean>
```

Then hand over the realm to your Security Manager:

```
<bean id="securityManager" class="org.apache.shiro.web.mgt.DefaultWebSecurityManager">
    <property name="realm" ref="ldapRealm" />
</bean>
```

Then, invoke the Login code wherever you want.